# How do I turn on color syntax highlighting in the macOS terminal app?

Tags: macos, terminal, ssh, color

When I use terminal it is monochrome, currently "Grass" yellow on green. I've tried several ssh clients: MacOS default terminal, Termius, and Core Shell. They all have the same result, no syntax highlighting.

Did I do something to turn it off? How can I turn it on?

[image]

Comment: What does 'echo $TERM' say? Does 'ls -G' work?

Comment: It says: `echo $TERM 
xterm-color`

Comment: ls -lG adds one more color (red) but not what I'm expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a look at this 
https://superuser.com/questions/400360/syntax-highlighting-in-terminal-mac-os-x post. In my view, it comes with a lot of useful hints.